# Shopware 6 admin api: User and Shop information

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

I'm developing an app for Shopware version 5 and 6, but this issue will be addressing mostly version 6.

**Is there a way to determine which user installed an app from a cloud marketplace or directly uploaded to self-hosted Shopware?**

My installation currently [works by using register and confirm endpoints](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-base-guide#confirmation) just fine and I get some identification (shop url and shop id) in the confirmation request. But I also need information about the shop name and user which installed the app.

After installation of the app, we need to finish the registration in our software and the standard way for us is to send an email to the user which triggered the registration (which should also contain information about the shop, like name).

(also some clues for shopware version 5 on the same topic will be appreciated, [at least it has shops endpoint resource](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/api-resource-shops/) which may be OK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a single shop name. There might be multiple sales channels with different names and apps are not bound to sales channels. Furthermore the information which user installed any given app or plugin is not tracked. What you can do is [read the system config via the API](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/configuration#reading-the-config-over-the-api) and get the name and email from the basic information settings. By omitting the sales channel id in the request you will get the fallback value used for all sales channels which is the closest to a default name and email for the system you can get. The domain for the basic information settings is `core.basicInformation`.

Shopware 5 is a completely different system and doesn't feature a registration-based app system geared to cloud-hosting like Shopware 6 has.

Comment: Is it better to contact the shop administrators about our further app onboarding using the `core.basicInformation.email` or retrieve and filter admin users from the API and rather inform them?

Comment: `core.basicInformation.email` is used in other places where emails are expected to be received by the responsible operator, so I would go with that. Admin users could include editors or contractors working as service providers of the actual operator.